# Remove span tag with specific class and attributes

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I need to remove a `<span class="" data-nid="">` tag with a specific class and attribute. I have looked up all similar answers on StackOverflow but to no avail.

I am trying to remove any span tag like this:

```
<span class="article-id post-id" data-nid="12563">some text</span>
```

Here is my attempt but it is not working:

```
    function remove_post_image( $content ){

      // replace any span with specific class

     $content = preg_replace('#<span class="article-id post-id".*?>(.*?)</span>#i', '', $content);


      return $content;
    }
    add_action('content_save_pre', 'remove_post_image');
```

Comment: does this have to be in PHP? Trying to manipulate HTML as a string has many complexities, doing it in JavaScript or with something else able to fully parse HTML to a DOM (and remember, HTML is not XML) is a lot easier. e.g. in jQuery:  `$('.article-id.post-id').remove()`.

Comment: yes please, php regex or mysql query.

Comment: pretty sure MySQL doing anything special is just impossible (well an extension could maybe do it), and regex likely only if you can 100% guarantee how the HTML is being generated (what if `class` is not the first attribute? What if the classes are in another order, or there are extra classes? How do you ensure you match the correct closing tag if there are nested spans? What if there is an unescaped `>` in a quoted attribute? etc.

Comment: span class is always first then comes the other attribute. Also the class value doesn't change. Except for data-nid attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`/<(span)\b.*?class=(['"\s]?)article-id post-id\2.*?>.*?<\/\1>/gi`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yYF7x6/1

Comment: $content = preg_replace('/<(span)\b.*?class=(['"\s]?)article-id post-id\2.*?>.*?<\/\1>/gi', '', $content);

It return Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'

Comment: You should note the many assumptions on the HTML this makes, like  no nested `span`, no extra white space, etc.

Comment: `$content = preg_replace('/<(span)\b.*?class=(['"\s]?)article-id post-id\2.*?>.*?<\/\1>/gi', '', $content);`

Could you rewrite it please ?

Comment: try: `$content = preg_replace('/<(span)\b.*?class=([\'"\s]?)article-id post-id\2.*?>.*?<\/\1>/gi', '', $content);`   I am a C# developer, not PHP, but just try :)

Comment: `$content` returns empty value. As if it deleted everything

Comment: I replaced /gi with i but it does not replace anything. I am using wordpress btw

Comment: Thank you I got it to work after I replaced `add_action('content_save_pre', 'remove_post_image');` with `add_action('the_content, 'remove_post_image');` 

I was hoping to delete the span tag before it is published..